# Showing that $h(x)\leq x+1$ for all $x \in [0,1].$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $h:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous nonnegative function such that
> $$h(x)^2 \leq 1+2 \int_0^x h(t)dt \quad \forall x \in [0,1].$$
> Show that $h(x)\leq 1+x$ for all $x \in [0,1].$

What I've been tried:

**Try 1:** Let $H(x)=\int_0^x h(t)dt.$ Hence $H'(x)=h(x)$ for every $x$. Now, by hypotesis we have that
$$H'(x)^2 \leq 1+2H(x).$$

I tried to do some trick like finding the derivative of the function $e^{-x}H(x),$ but it was unsuccesfull.

**Try 2:** Since $h$ is continuous over $[0,1]$ then $h$  attains a maximum value $M=h(c)$ for some $c \in [0,1].$ Now, using the hypotesis and the fact that
$\int_0^x h(t)dt \leq \int_0^x Mdt=Mx \leq M,$ then we have:
$$M^2\leq 1+2M.$$
After some computations over $M$, I couldn't find interesting information to show the desired result.

Can you help me in solving this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an assumption that $h(x)$ is a differentiable function?

Comment: @Jun No, only continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H$ is by construction positive for $x>0$ and growing, $H'\ge 0$. Thus
$$
(\sqrt{1+2H(x)})'=\frac{H'(x)}{\sqrt{1+2H(x)}}\le 1
$$
integrates to
$$
\sqrt{1+2H(x)}-1\le x,
$$
from where the claim directly follows.